# ArrayList that I fill in a function doesn’t affect the ArrayList in the rest of the code even if I return the changed ArrayList as a return value

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my UserMaganamentFragment:

```
private static final String TAG = "UserManagamentFragment";
private List<String> mEmails  = new ArrayList<>();
private FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_managament, container, false);

    getEmails();

    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter( mEmails, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return view;
}

private void getEmails(){

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    db.collection("users")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            mEmails.add(document.getData().get("email").toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

`
I even tried adding everything in the OnCreateView function but it still didn't affect the mEmails arrayList.

mEmail is full with data at the end of the getEmails function.

Comment: Looks like getEmails executed asynchornously. basically the rest of code is executed before onComplete function is called. In documentation you can find code for blocking operation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: All read from/write to Firestore is asynchronous. There is no blocking operation.

Comment: please post your adapter class

Comment: As FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, all Firestore operations are asynchronous. Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behavior and how can you solve this using a custom callback.